# Marginal ANOVA test in R

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to run a marginal (also called type-III) ANOVA using the following code. Unfortunately, I get "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". A google search turned up another person getting the same error ([see here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://menzerath.phonetik.uni-frankfurt.de/teaching/R/R_05.pdf&ei=x2wFU9eBKcfsoATf14CIDw&usg=AFQjCNGBEsc0ay58PZJxPfiGsg-LdIWV1A&sig2=-w6hdgPBnJ7bE3dP8o589A&bvm=bv.61725948,d.cGU&cad=rja)), but unfortunately no solutions.

```
rm(list = ls())

data(iris)

iris.lm <- lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length , data = iris)
print(anova(object = iris.lm))
print(anova(object = iris.lm , type = "marginal"))
```

Comment: maybe you have this confused with `nlme::anova.lme`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference, the function `Anova` from the package `car` accepts a `type` argument (such as `"III"` or `3`). This function is not to be confused with the function `anova` from the standard `R` library, which does not accept a `type` argument.

Comment: So really the answer to this question is that the poster wants to be using `Anova()` from the `cars` package not `anova()` from base.  I too have made this mistake!  It's great being able to run into this comment, as I feel like this probably happens a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Using a `traceback` you can localize the error:

```
print(anova(object = iris.lm , type = "marginal"))
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> traceback()
7: deparse(x$terms[[2L]])
6: FUN(X[[2L]], ...)
5: lapply(objects, function(x) deparse(x$terms[[2L]]))
4: anova.lmlist(object, ...)
3: anova.lm(object = iris.lm, type = "marginal")
2: anova(object = iris.lm, type = "marginal")
1: print(anova(object = iris.lm, type = "marginal"))
```

So you get the error because you try to call `terms` on an object that not support it. This reproduce the error:

```
 lapply(list(iris.lm,type='marginal'),terms)
 Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Or just :

```
terms('marginal')
```

But Why do you expect that this works? Maybe I miss something, but I think it is not mentioned that anova can take `type` as an argument.